# Creating a `Pin<Box<[T; N]>>` in Rust when `[T; N]` is too large to be created on the stack

Tags: rust, allocation, maybeuninit

### Generalized Question

**How can I implement a general function `pinned_array_of_default` in stable Rust where `[T; N]` is too large to fit on the stack?**

```rust
fn pinned_array_of_default<T: Default, const N: usize>() -> Pin<Box<[T; N]>> {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Alternatively, `T` can implement `Copy` if that makes the process easier.

```rust
fn pinned_array_of_element<T: Copy, const N: usize>(x: T) -> Pin<Box<[T; N]>> {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Keeping the solution in safe Rust would have been preferable, but it seems unlikely that it is possible.

### Approaches

Initially I was hopping that by implementing `Default` I might be able to get `Default` to handle the initial allocation, however it still creates it on the stack so this will not work for large values of `N`.

```rust
let boxed: Box<[T; N]> = Box::default();
let foo = Pin::new(boxed);
```

I suspect I need to use `MaybeUninit` to achieve this and there is a `Box::new_uninit()` function, but it is currently unstable and I would ideally like to keep this within stable Rust. I also somewhat unsure if transmuting `Pin<Box<MaybeUninit<B>>>` to `Pin<Box<B>>` could somehow have negative effects on the `Pin`.

### Background

The purpose behind using a `Pin<Box<[T; N]>>` is to hold a block of pointers where `N` is some constant factor/multiple of the page size.

```rust
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub union Foo<R: ?Sized> {
    assigned: NonNull<R>,
    next_unused: Option<NonNull<Self>>,
}
```

Each pointer may or may not be in use at a given point in time. An in-use `Foo` points to `R`, and an unused/empty `Foo` has a pointer to either the next empty `Foo` in the block or `None`. A pointer to the first unused `Foo` in the block is stored separately. When a block is full, a new block is created and then pointer chain of unused positions continues through the next block.

The box needs to be pinned since it will contain self referential pointers as well as outside structs holding pointers into assigned positions in each block.

**I know that `Foo` is wildly unsafe by Rust standards, but the general question of creating a `Pin<Box<[T; N]>>` still stands**

Comment: A possible approach: create a `Vec` of length `N`, then use `Vec::into_boxed_slice` to get a `Box<[T]>`, and then you can [`.try_into()` a `Box<[T; N]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html#impl-TryFrom%3CBox%3C%5BT%5D%2C%20Global%3E%3E).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A way to construct a large array on the heap and avoid creating it on the stack is to proxy through a `Vec`. You can construct the elements and use [`.into_boxed_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice) to get a `Box<[T]>`. You can then use [`.try_into()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-TryFrom%3CBox%3C%5BT%5D%2C%20Global%3E%3E) to convert it to a `Box<[T; N]>`. And then use [`.into()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#impl-From%3CBox%3CT%2C%20A%3E%3E) to convert it to a `Pin<Box<[T; N]>>`:

```
fn pinned_array_of_default<T: Default, const N: usize>() -> Pin<Box<[T; N]>> {
    let mut vec = vec![];
    vec.resize_with(N, T::default);
    let boxed: Box<[T; N]> = match vec.into_boxed_slice().try_into() {
        Ok(boxed) => boxed,
        Err(_) => unreachable!(),
    };
    
    boxed.into()
}
```

You can optionally make this look more straight-forward if you add `T: Clone` so that you can do `vec![T::default(); N]` and/or add `T: Debug` so you can use `.unwrap()` or `.expect()`.

See also:

- [Creating a fixed-size array on heap in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805174/creating-a-fixed-size-array-on-heap-in-rust)

Comment: I'd keep `unreachable!()`, even if you could require `Debug` in that case, because it conveys that this will never happen, and can be easily replaced with `unreachable_unchecked` in the future if necessary.

Comment: Will `.into_boxed_slice().try_into()` cause the contents to be copied to create the new `Box`?

Comment: No, it essentially just transmutes unless the slice isn't long enough: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#1552 You could implement the `from_raw(into_raw)` yourself if you'd prefer to avoid the `try_into`.

Comment: @Locke The [`.into_boxed_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#995) call may re-allocate if there is unused capacity because a box must refer to the whole allocation. However, with a resize from 0->N, that would only happen with [certain combinations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/raw_vec.rs.html#111) of small `N` and `size_of::<T>()`.